# How can get disk usage in linux using c program?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-18.04

I want to get disk usage in linux but when I run above code, the result is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    const unsigned int GB = (1024 * 1024) * 1024;
    struct statvfs buffer;
    int ret = statvfs("/dev/sda4", &buffer);

    if (!ret) {
        const double total = (double)(buffer.f_blocks * buffer.f_frsize) / GB;
        const double available = (double)(buffer.f_bfree * buffer.f_frsize) / GB;
        const double used = total - available;
        const double usedPercentage = (double)(used / total) * (double)100;
        printf("Total: %f --> %.0f\n", total, total);
        printf("Available: %f --> %.0f\n", available, available);
        printf("Used: %f --> %.1f\n", used, used);
        printf("Used Percentage: %f --> %.0f\n", usedPercentage, usedPercentage);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
Total: 7.757446 --> 8
Available: 7.757446 --> 8
Used: 0.000000 --> 0.0
Used Percentage: 0.000000 --> 0
```

**I run df command in linux terminal. The output is:**

```
Filesystem       1K-blocks    Used  Available   Use% Mounted on      
**/dev/sda4      471705824 13885152 433789596   4% /**
```

These two result is different from each other. What is the reason?

Comment: You can change to `const double GB = 1024.0 * 1024 * 1024;` and `100.0` and remove all of the unnecessary casts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use the device "/dev/sda4". You have to use a path, where the device has been mounted like "/" or "/home". If you use the device name, you get the result for the "udev" filesystem.

Comment: Right, I changed the path with "/". I need to display disk usage of /dev/sda4. But again results are not same.                                                                                                                    
/dev/sda4   Available:  414G  when I run "df -h /" command.                                                But program output is Available is 437GB

Comment: @engineer See the difference between [GB and GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte). You calculate GiB, which is smaller than GB.